# About sending Multiple mails

Tags: asp.net

I tried to sending a mail but it doesn't contain multiple mails Only one mail.How to send multiple mail in asp.net? 
And content of mail should be specified for different mail users

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer.  Multiple mails?  Do you mean multiple recipients?  Or multiple emails to the same recipient?  Or same email but using a template?  Post your code

Comment: Also adding multiple TO fields will allow everyone you add to see each others emails.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question correct, you mean multiple recipients?

You could try something like this:

```
string yourEmail = "mural@krish.com"; 
using (MailMessage send = new MailMessage())
{
    send.From = new MailAddress(yourEmail);
    send.To.Add("recipient@mailaddress.com");
    send.To.Add("recipient2@mailaddress.com");
}
```

Otherwise, if you want multiple emails, you can try this:

```
// if you want to run this multiple times, 
// just wrap this in a function, and call it however many times you want.
var startHTML = "<html><head></head><body>";
var endHTML = "</body></html>";
var emailArray = ["email1","email2","email3"]; 
foreach (string emailAddress in emailArray)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); // your mailclient.
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(emailAddress);
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Body = startHTML +
        "<p>Your Message :) </p>" +
         endHTML;
    msg.Subject = "Email Subject";
    msg.To.Add(to);

    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

OP asked:

**"This is Okay but i need to send different messages to different mail address at once is it possible"**

```
var startHTML = "<html><head></head><body>";
var endHTML = "</body></html>";
var messageList = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("recipient1@gmail.com", "your custom message1"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("recipient2@gmail.com", "your custom message2"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("recipient3@gmail.com", "your custom message3"),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("recipient4@gmail.com", "your custom message4"),
};

foreach (var receiver in messageList)
{
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient(); // your mailclient.
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(receiver.Key);
    msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
    msg.Body = startHTML +
        receiver.Value +
         endHTML;
    msg.Subject = "Email Subject";
    msg.To.Add(to);

    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
```

Comment: This is Okay but i need to send different messages to different mail address at once is it possible

Comment: Can u send any program about this!!

Comment: But i was confused by your answer

Comment: @muralkrish I have answered your question. You can't change what you want. You have to ask a new question then. Please mark this as an answer as it DOES answer your original question.

Comment: What you entered in string value i was confused about that and then i want to send mail by using what i get mail from textbox or labelbox